# How should I design images size to support all iOS Devices Retina Display

Tags: ios, xcode, retina-display

I'm developing a Universal Card Game and I will use different card size for iPhone-3.5inch , iPhone-4inch, iPad and iPad mini. I need the card to support Retina Display, so should I create 4 images ? like :

- card_iphone35@2x.png
- card_iphone4@2x.png
- card_ipad@2x.png
- card_ipad-mini@2x.png

or I only create 1 image for iPad Retina Display and then I use it for example in iPhone-3.5inch with UIImageView being scaled down ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should create an image for every device.

I recommend you to check iOS Human Interface Guidelines, it explain everything abut sizes, icons, images...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html